# Virtual hosts on apache to point domain.com, domain.net, domain.org to all go to domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, rewrite

All of the names currently point to the same web server folder which is correct. That is, the domain.net, domain.org, etc all work without redirecting to the main .com

How do I get visits to the .org and .net to redirect the browser to domain.com?

This should be basic, but I am can't figure out the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `RewriteRule` from `mod_rewrite` than use `Redirect` from `mod_alias`. As mod rewrite is more versatile.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName domain.org
     ServerAlias www.domain.org domain.net www. domain.net
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.(net|org)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/documentroot
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` **uncommented**.

Explanation:

---

```
     RewriteEngine on
```

Sets the `RewriteEngine` on

---

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.(net|org)$ [NC]
```

Matches `%{HTTP_HOST}`: i.e: The base URL of the host. For more on `RewriteCond` & `http headers` visit: [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). 
`[NC]` is a flag: 'nocase|NC' (no case)

This makes the test case-insensitive - differences between 'A-Z' and 'a-z' are ignored, both in the expanded TestString and the CondPattern. This flag is effective only for comparisons between TestString and CondPattern. It has no effect on filesystem and subrequest checks.

Also you have to redirect URL's that start with WWW as well. 
that is why `^(www\.)` in the pattern.

---

```
     RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Rewrites the URL to `domain.com` if a match in `RewriteCond` Occurs. Adds any request URI if present. i.e. The URI for this request (relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT).

if URl was: `domain.com/web/hello.php` then `REQUEST_URI=/web/hello.php`

---

Comment: This is a good solution if your redirects are tricky or conditional, but if you just need to change hostnames whilst preserving paths the `Redirect` solution is simpler IMO (and more readable).

Comment: @nickgrim I agree its simpler. I am trying to take care of most cases here.

Answer (score 2):

@Pasta,

What I do in this particular situation is to create a separate virtualhost block

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName domain.net
   ServerAlias domain.org

   Redirect permanent http://domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps.

Ismael Casimpan

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference between ServerName, ServerAlias?

Comment: With that solution, a request to say `http://domain.org/articles/view/123/comments` will just be redirected to `http://domain.com/` without the rest of the URI. That's not too bright if people have bookmarked deeplinks to the `.org` or `.net` hosts for example

Comment: @Pasta You can only have one `ServerName`, and it's intended to be canonical. You can have as many `ServerAlias`es as you like. Docs are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#ServerName).

Comment: @JudasIscariot1651 That's completely not true; the [documentation for Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect) states "Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL".

Comment: @nickgrim I apologize for my ignorance, I seldom use mod_alias, always mod_rewrite